# Trying to observe two IntVar with tkinter and pick the lowest number

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi everyone I'm currently working on an rpg dynamic character sheet in python and I'm mainly using the tkinter library but I have come to an obstacle preventing me from going on.

What I am trying to achieve is getting two numbers from spinboxes (called `con` and `vol`) that can vary from 1 to 10 and compare the two to display the lowest number on a label (`terre`) next to the spinboxes in real time.
For instance, if `con` is equal to 2 and `vol` equal to 3, then `terre` should display 2, if `con` gets added +1, then `terre` would be equal to 3 since `con` = 3 and `vol` = 3 and so on and so on.

The problem I'm having is that `terre` doesn't seem to be connected to `con` and `vol` and is not updating properly, when I change the numbers in the spinbox of the two variable, `terre` stays the same (that is to say 0) and won't budge.

My script so far is the following (sorry if it looks bad I'm still very new to programing) :

```
def Terre_calcul(*args) :
    tr1 = int(con.get())
    tr2 = int(vol.get())
    if tr1 > tr2 :
        terreV.set(vol.get())
    else : 
        terreV.set(con.get())

#################################

#creation of the parent widget
win = Tk()
win.title("Fiche personnage")

#widgets dimensions
win.geometry("800x1029+0+0")
win.resizable(width= False, height= False)

##################################

#Constitution 
con = IntVar()
conE = Spinbox(win, from_= 1, to= 10, width= 1, textvariable= con)
conE.place(x= 180, y= 165)
con.set(conE.get())

#Volonté
vol = IntVar()
volE = Spinbox(win, from_= 1, to= 10, width= 1, textvariable= vol)
volE.place(x= 168, y= 196)
vol.set(volE.get())

#Score
terreV = IntVar()
terre = Label(win, textvariable= terreV)
terre.tkraise(aboveThis= None)
terre.place(x= 266, y= 212)

win.mainloop()
```

Ignore some of the french gibberish it's really unimportant.
I'd be more than happy to answer any further question and I hope you can help me with this problem, thank you in advance :).

Comment: You typed `tr2 = int(con.get())` instead of `tr2 = int(vol.get())`. That said, could you please be more clear as to what the problem is? We know what you're trying to do, but you didn't specify _why_ the code you have doesn't do that. Did you get any error messages? Were the numbers incorrect?

Comment: You've stated what you're building, but you haven't asked a question. What part of the problem do you need help with? You write that you've come to an obstacle. What is that obstacle?

Comment: yes very sorry I just edited the problem in and changed my error on `tr2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `Terre_calcul` to `command` option of the two spinboxes:

```py
...
conE = Spinbox(win, from_= 1, to= 10, width= 5, textvariable= con, command=Terre_calcul)
...
volE = Spinbox(win, from_= 1, to= 10, width= 5, textvariable= vol, command=Terre_calcul)
...
Terre_calcul() # update terreV initially
win.mainloop()
```

Then whenever the value of one of the spinboxes is changed, `Terre_calcul()` will be executed.